# Vertical delete in IdeaVIM

Tags: vim, ideavim

In my normal VIM installation, I can select vertically with `ctrl+v`, move down and over however many lines, and then hit `x` to delete everything I've highlighted.

In IdeaVIM, doing the same thing only deletes the single character that I am highlighting with my cursor at the time.

Does anyone know how to change the IdeaVIM behavior to the regular VIM behavior?

Comment: i think ideavim is just busted. the block select never worked well, and then someone "upgraded" it and made it worse...

Comment: since intellij(or other product) brought the new feature multi-selection, the ideavim's block-wise selection and its operation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in IdeaVIM version 0.36, released 2014-10-14.  The bug is tracked in [VIM-632](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-632).  Note off-by-one error tracked in [VIM-501](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-501) is fixed in an upcoming release (probably will be called 0.38).